# CVA - Where does the default probability (PD) come from?

Tags: default-probability, cva, counterparty-risk

Some authors use CDS from the market to derive the implied default probability (from a risk-neutral point of view).

I wonder: how exactly does a CDS reflect counterparty risk?

Let me put an example: let's say I would like to price a derivative instrument (rate) that I am negotiating with counterparty $A$. I need to include the CVA (counterparty credit risk). Should I look for the CDS of $A$ in the market? I thought CDS reflect the debt issuer default risk, but maybe it also reflects counterparty credit risk.

Can someone clarify this please?

Comment: A good question in fact. Typically standard CDS contracts (when yours truly last traded them) had 3 default triggers: Bankruptcy, Restructuring, Failure to Pay. None of these encompass failure to perform under Swap Obligations. This latter constitutes a '4th trigger', which may be documented for certain bespoke contracts however standard CDS would only be a proxy for this 'event'. Regardless, standard terms implied default probabilities is how CVAs generally got marked, in the absence of any observable market in '4th trigger' CDS.

Comment: Fyi - a simple derivative like an interest rate swap is not Borrowed Money. This is the standard term for the Obligation Category under which a Credit Event can be triggered (all capitalised terms are legally defined). Borrowed Money is a Bond / Loan, deposit or drawn down portion of a credit facility. Not an interest rate swap. So, as stated, standard terms CDS will not trigger if a counterparty refuses to pay a bank under an IRS, but honours coupons to bondholders. Now there are layers of documentation that mean that the global ISDA might collapse with implications (which haven't thought...

Comment: ..through yet), but just worth making the point that CVAs are hedged with CDS, however this is under a prevailing assumption, nothing more, that they are a good proxy. This is why as mentioned in comments it is tough to get regulatory recognition for vanilla CDS language-documented hedge trades (at least was when present dude last involved). If someone currently involved can set the record straight on reg treatment of contingent CDS hedge trades would be great! enough spiel I think but like I say these definitional details are very poorly socialised in math finance in general

Answer (score 5):

"Debt issuer default risk" and "counterparty risk" are very similar. From [*Risk*](https://www.risk.net/definition/counterparty-risk) magazine:

> **Counterparty Risk**
>
> The risk that a counterparty to a transaction or contract will default (fail to perform) on its obligation under the contract. Counterparty risk is not limited to credit risk (the risk that the counterparty cannot fulfill its contractual obligations for payment) but may also result from other problems associated with a counterparty unwilling to honor the contract.

In practice, it is implicitly assumed the material part of CVA can be captured by CDS prices. Quantifying other sources of counterparty risk would be particularly challenging due to the absence of legal precedents (bear in mind that the CDS market is only 25 years old).

Now suppose you have entered into some interest rate derivative contract with your counterparty $A$. The contract has maturity $T$ and its value at $t<T$ is given by $V(t)$. Your **exposure $E(t)$** at time $t$ is equal to the positive value of the contract:
$$E(t)=\max(0,V(t))$$
CVA is the *price* of the risk of default of your counterparty thus you need to look at the future *expected* exposure *under the risk-neutral measure*. Enter the **risk-neutral discounted expected exposure $EE^Q(t,u)$** for a time $t<u<T$:
$$EE^Q(t,u) = E^Q_t[D(t,u)E(u)]$$
where $Q$ is the risk-neutral measure and $D(t,u)$ the discount factor from $u$ to $t$. This corresponds to the risk-neutral value at time $t$ of the future value *to you* of the derivative contract, namely what you stand to lose if your counterparty defaults (or is "unwilling to honor the contract"). The default can occur at any time $u$ between $t$ and $T$, hence CVA for counterparty $A$ at time $t$ is equal to (assuming a recovery rate $\text{Rec}$):
$$\text{CVA}_A(t)=(1-\text{Rec})\int_t^TEE^Q(t,u)\color{blue}{\text{d}P_t^Q(u)}$$
where $\text{d}P_t^Q(u)$ is the risk-neutral probability of default of $A$ on the infinitesimal time interval $[u,u+\text{d}u]$, conditional on the current ($t$) information.

To obtain estimates of default probabilities, you can extract information from the CDS market for counterparty $A$. To understand this, consider the following toy example: assume the risk-free rate is constant equal to $r$ and there exists a contract with a $1$-year maturity which pays $1\times(1-\text{Rec})$ if counterparty $A$ defaults within the year in exchange for a CDS premium $s_A$. By risk-neutral theory:
$$\begin{align}
s_A &= E^Q[e^{-r}(1-\text{Rec})1_{\{A \text{ defaults within 1 year\}}}]
\\[3pt]
& = e^{-r}(1-\text{Rec})\color{blue}{P^Q(A \text{ defaults within 1 year})}
\end{align}$$
Thus:
$$\color{blue}{P^Q(A \text{ defaults within 1 year})}=e^r\frac{s_A}{1-\text{Rec}}$$
You observe that CDS premiums encapsulate expected default information. You could also consider that distributional information $P^Q(\cdot)$ contained by CDS premiums is not limited to default *but* includes *any* failure to pay: this would probably depend on the design of the CDS contract and its payment triggers.

Anyway, in practice to price CVA we only look at the probability information contained by CDSs and assume it captures any material event that might result in no payment.

**[Edit]** In practice you also need to consider *which* CDS you choose: different CDSs might have different contractual designs and definitions of "default", thus some CDSs might not be relevant to quantify the probability of default/no payment/etc. for a particular derivative contract $V(t)$. See comments from @Mehness.

**References**

Pykhtin, M. and Zhu, S. (2007). "A Guide to Modelling Counterparty Credit Risk", *GARP Risk Review*.

Comment: Hi - legally it is not necessarily true that an FTP will trigger under a failure to perform under a swap obligation. Market participants for the most part don't really worry about this too much and make the assumption in your final sentence, however for example if trying legally to document a contingent CDS for a bespoke trade, you have to insert additional triggering language. This comment would have been current as of the 2013 ISDA definitions FYI.

Comment: this gleaned from experience putting together such trades with legal assistance from members of ISDAs Credit Events Determination Committee. However just mentioning for strict correctness, obviously this is less interesting than the pricing above and an annoying detail. Sadly a vanilla CDS is not necessarily a hedge for a counterparty that fails to make a payment under a swap confirm - this may not trigger an Event of Default (don't have the 2013 defs to hand else could point to the relevant clauses).

Comment: I see, I am not that familiar with the legal details of CDS and how "credit events" are rigorously defined. From a CVA perspective, of course you will extract distributional information from the CDS which is most relevant to the trade you are entering with your counterparty and assume this information is sufficient. This gets all the more convoluted than you sometimes need to price CVA on a netting set basis and the CDS must be representative of all the trades contained in that netting set.

Comment: Sure - I guess the point is that everyone learns standard pricing as per the above, however if you actually have the trades on your book, you really really care about the precise legal definition, even the vintage of the documents can mattermaterially (see asset packages as novel deliverable obligations for sovereign defaults - massively changes the default contingent payoffs introduced after sovereign debt crisis c2010ff). If you have any trigger basis in your book you are exposed to gross notional risk, so you really have to get the triggering precisely aligned. just...

Comment: ...trying to find a proper legal reference - [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwiogL6z9LPeAhVrJsAKHSGgCNIQFjACegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblogs.lexisnexis.co.uk%2Floanranger%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2Fsites%2F9%2F2014%2F07%2Fjibfljuly2014pdf.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3dVdDhVp1vWDwOofJD5I0I) offers some background on the 2014 defs and the sovereign update i mentioned. (the first author is one whose expertise have sought on some of the aboove points - he basically wrote the definitions) I believe an interest swap is not a Qualifying Obligation but need to ccheck

Comment: @Mehness "_[...] if you actually have the trades on your book, you really really care about the precise legal definition_" do you mean **CDS trades** or **CVA pricing/hedging trades**? I assume a CDS trader will of course carefully look at trigger definitions etc., but if you're a CVA trader you're not trying to match a specific CDS to each trade for which you are hedging the CVA, are you?

Comment: Sure - which is why no one bothers about this too much - effectively treating standard triggers as subsuming failure to pay a swap coupon stream. EXCEPT when a CVA trader might want to get regulatory capital relief for a counterparty specific derivative MTM-contingent CDS hedge.  A vanilla CDS contract against the counterparty, whose payoff is linked to the portfolio of swaps vs that counterparty, may not be seen by a regulator as hedging the cprty risk if it doesn't have the right trigger (even if in this case the payoff is rates/inflation based etc...). So this can be material to a CVA desk.

Comment: But as I say, these are details that don't matter to much for day to day XVA risk management, it's only if eg you are trying to get Reg Cap recognition for a hedge trade, or if a counterparty stops paying under a swap but the CVA hedge CDSs don't trigger for some arcane lack of completeness in legal terms so you wear the swap MTM loss unhedged, that it matters. At least this was the state of play not super long ago...

Comment: I feel as a service to the community owe a proper legal answer to this (coming from a trader not a lawyer though). Will write out in time, however in short, unlike interest rate swaps etc, credit derivatives definitions are actually highly non-trivial both with respect to trigger and payoff, however all pricing textbooks/papers I have ever seen, no matter how beautiful the particular levy process chosen for the stochastic intensity (correlated with other asset class processes etc..) completely gloss over this point. For example, I think many on this forum would be surprised if I told...

Comment: ...them that If I have bought and sold 10mm CDS to the same maturity on the same corporate name struck at the same coupon, I am not necessarily flat risk in a Restructuring credit event during the settlement process: The buyer will trigger into their own maturity bucket for bonds, however if seller triggers first their payoff will be driven by the longest maturity bucket, which may (and has on many occasions I have managed) be tens of points different. On this simple 'book' this can have an impact of millions, far more important than the basis points impact hazard rate mean reversion!

Comment: Anyway details like this around triggers and the precise definitions of admittedly difficult to define / encompass corporate events are generally completely ignored by standard math finance texts as mentioned (fair enough as you cannot model these things really but a mention wouldn't hurt!), maybe it's the kind of stuff you only appreciate trading the stuff (including CVA/hybrid trades/anything credit - linked). So, the OP's a good question and the strictly correct answer is non-trivial, with significant regulatory implications for CVA desks a few years back.. Too many comments, apologies!